# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/BytecodeInterface8

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports, ireport

Tenho um relatório e preciso usar sub reports, mas sempre que tento usar, encontro esssa exceção:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/BytecodeInterface8
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : "/home/juliana/NetBeansProjects/SistemaWeb/SistemaWeb-war/web/relatorios/meuRelatorio/"
```

Caso eu não use subreport, o relatório e gerado normalmente. Já tentei várias alternativas para tentar resolver o problema, mas até agora sem sucesso

**XML do Relatório**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="20345f4c-6c2a-42bd-9b2e-f2102198a3c2">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="407"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/home/juliana/NetBeansProjects/SistemaWeb/SistemaWeb-war/web/relatorios/meuRelatorio/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<field name="idLivroOrdem" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="dataCriacao" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="dataRealInicioObraServico" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="art.numeroArt" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.nomeProfissionalContratado" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.rnpProfissionalContratado" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.titulosProfissionalContratado" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.registroRegionalProfissionalContratado" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.enderecoObraServico.tipoLogradouro" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.enderecoObraServico.logradouro" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.enderecoObraServico.numero" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.enderecoObraServico.bairro" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.enderecoObraServico.cidade" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.enderecoObraServico.uf" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.enderecoObraServico.cep" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.nomeProprietario" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.cpfCnpjProprietario" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="art.atividadesArtAntigas" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="relatos" class="java.util.List"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="88" splitType="Stretch">
        <image>
            <reportElement uuid="b9926800-5924-43ce-b890-0c69175b4be2" x="17" y="24" width="58" height="50"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/juliana/NetBeansProjects/SistemaWeb/SistemaWeb-war/web/relatorios/brasaoReport.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="c984a13e-1766-4d56-9810-32a4ce516b9c" x="18" y="74" width="57" height="14"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[RELATORIO]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
            <reportElement uuid="b52bd63b-2318-4e33-ad46-80742e42ce7c" x="18" y="3" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="HH:mm">
            <reportElement uuid="d340f061-db24-4dc2-9dae-bd865c759e0c" x="497" y="4" width="58" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="658063ed-4935-4091-98ee-960dd560b63b" x="169" y="67" width="219" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[Resolução CONFEA N. 1094 de 31/10/2017]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="5d4c0c9e-2c99-4a05-bfb5-d58412055fc7" x="397" y="34" width="51" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Livro Nº]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="c96c6f9e-f852-4790-b4c6-0ff5a9e85f84" x="401" y="62" width="27" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ART]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="0de103ba-c090-4bde-ba42-296ca8b15b61" x="213" y="34" width="122" height="28"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Livro de Ordem]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement uuid="66b6d0aa-1f5e-44d3-b495-d7566a790013" x="448" y="34" width="107" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idLivroOrdem}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement uuid="7e72d780-1d5f-44ff-a154-2b7fa71a65cb" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="428" y="62" width="127" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.numeroArt}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="345" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="73c0382e-3edd-4a6f-8402-73ff04fb8cf8" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="10" width="525" height="111"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="1b994936-15dd-4b52-acad-8aa96655daec" x="25" y="21" width="167" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[RESPONSÁVEL TÉCNICO]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="308c5741-335b-4490-938c-d36c4bc4f8d9" x="25" y="88" width="132" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Título Profissional: ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="37d92aa9-f250-4976-ba30-0c736d57452d" x="345" y="49" width="42" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[RNP: ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="f38fd7f3-9b95-40ef-93c0-3a74e666cfed" x="372" y="88" width="56" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Registro: ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="041e531d-506e-44f3-9482-065e299b4284" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="131" width="525" height="204"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="c2984258-b211-48ff-888d-912bf2af44f0" x="20" y="144" width="190" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[DADOS DA OBRA/SERVIÇO]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="5c34c7f2-f5cf-4ba9-8481-fdee3737f054" x="20" y="237" width="85" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Proprietário: ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="ea60b9d7-59da-43c8-b9f5-54399418799e" x="299" y="237" width="69" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[CPF/CNPJ: ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="08e1c840-2ba1-4b80-9a38-e83f94970dca" x="20" y="300" width="242" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Data Real de Início da Obra/Serviço:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="956a35d2-d3d3-4e48-8aec-c064de3fc3c2" x="20" y="269" width="172" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Data de Abertura do Livro: ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement uuid="8c095ac4-50e4-4c65-8a4d-dc2dde2e8d9f" x="25" y="49" width="310" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.nomeProfissionalContratado}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="f197c9ff-6a88-46cf-bb4a-ec6f554fc609" x="387" y="49" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.rnpProfissionalContratado}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="35d833ae-4e76-46e0-a7fc-3e4b758d5593" x="428" y="88" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.registroRegionalProfissionalContratado}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="6acae8c1-c3d7-43d9-bcde-98b16fdd8b2c" x="157" y="88" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.titulosProfissionalContratado}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="2f4cc7ae-63fb-480f-9e4c-958add716f24" x="24" y="171" width="101" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.enderecoObraServico.tipoLogradouro}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="ffc14974-a57e-4ec3-b550-6864e0a00737" x="446" y="171" width="82" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.enderecoObraServico.numero}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="2ab24562-4de4-4c60-9658-0425ea3f0b1d" x="25" y="195" width="188" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.enderecoObraServico.bairro}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="97b13707-c732-4e24-ae5c-a72b04ce14af" x="220" y="195" width="148" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.enderecoObraServico.cidade}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="ff625d8e-02ca-450f-82bb-c772495f683c" x="373" y="195" width="41" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.enderecoObraServico.uf}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="ca219071-ef0d-46bc-807e-50578559dca3" x="428" y="195" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.enderecoObraServico.cep}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="952b3171-59b5-4041-b03e-1cf8b2517be5" x="105" y="237" width="189" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.nomeProprietario}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="59ebd520-b78d-4c2f-8a75-8f77469c46d4" x="373" y="237" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.cpfCnpjProprietario}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="deee2765-35ff-4f06-9e9c-0ab01ac5a0bf" x="199" y="269" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dataCriacao}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
            <reportElement uuid="36b94535-b3f3-4742-9a0f-4631ad60ea53" x="262" y="300" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dataRealInicioObraServico}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="a83796be-169e-45b9-878f-d693add9d3ab" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="131" y="171" width="297" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{art.enderecoObraServico.logradouro}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
    <band height="126">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="f0d1de0c-2f50-44d8-a3a2-81e97ac36829" x="20" y="26" width="137" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ATIVIDADE TÉCNICA]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="c2a07437-cfa5-45a7-a000-7b7bf95d8482" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="15" width="525" height="95"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineStyle="Dotted"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </rectangle>
    </band>
    <band height="257">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="5d941d6e-2157-41f6-96d9-f3ebb0df4745" x="9" y="8" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[RELATOS]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement uuid="7ff6cc78-e7d5-463d-8803-d4f31edef562" x="10" y="38" width="524" height="208"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{relatos})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "relatos.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="4a2c60f0-dfad-425e-b0b2-0acad3c6cd54" x="214" y="14" width="80" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement uuid="aa17bcf8-b782-4986-8fde-17b96803f1d8" x="294" y="14" width="40" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

**Método de Impressão**

```
public static void imprimirLivroOrdem(LivroOrdem livroOrdem) throws Exception {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    String caminho = "/relatorios/";
    String subPasta = caminho + "livroOrdem/";
    String relatorio = subPasta + "livroOrdem.jasper";

    livroOrdem.setRelatos(relatos);
    List<LivroOrdem> livrosOrdem = new ArrayList<LivroOrdem>();
    livrosOrdem.add(livroOrdem);

    InputStream reportStream = context.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(relatorio);

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", context.getExternalContext().getRealPath(subPasta) + File.separator);
    map.put("BRASAO_DIR", context.getExternalContext().getRealPath(caminho) + File.separator);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=livroOrdem.pdf");
    //response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=livroOrdem.pdf");

    try {
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource fonteDados = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(livrosOrdem);

        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, map, fonteDados);
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    } 

    catch (JRException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 

    finally {
        context.responseComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual o seu código?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, Editei a pergunta com o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se seu subreport não está configurado com a linguagem Groovy ao invés de Java:

1. Na aba Propriedades, mude o atributo Linguagem / Language de Groovy para Java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz isso e o relatório é imprimido agora, mas em branco, vou editar a pergunta e botar o codigo do subreport na resposta

Comment: Recomendo abrir uma nova questão visto que agora você tem um novo problema provavelmente relacionado ao datasource enviado ao subreport, mais pessoas vão conseguir te ajudar :)

Comment: Ok. Farei isso, então. Obrigada!